# gcc assembler not recognizing tzcntl or lzcntl though my processor does

Tags: c, built-in

If I compile this C function:

```
int function(unsigned u) {
  int r = __builtin_clz(u) + __builtin_ctz(u);
  return r;
}
```

in clang using `-march=native`, I get the following assembly:

```
pushq   %rbp
movq    %rsp, %rbp
lzcntl  %edi, %ecx
tzcntl  %edi, %eax
addl    %ecx, %eax
popq    %rbp
retq
```

and the compiled object code runs fine on my processor. (I'm on a Mac OS, so I query the CPU features using `sysctl -a machdep.cpu`. It reports the BMI1 capability which includes TZCNT, and also the LZCNT capability. Also if I link that into a binary and execute it I get the expected results.)

If I compile the same code using gcc using `-march=native`, I get similar assembly:

```
xorl    %eax, %eax
lzcntl  %edi, %eax
tzcntl  %edi, %edi
addl    %edi, %eax
ret
```

but the assembler refuses to compile it. I get `no such instruction` errors for both the `lzcntl` and the `tzcntl`. What do I need to do to get the assembler to cooperate? Is it feasible/reasonable to tell gcc to use a different assembler? If so, how do I do that?

I'm not trying to solve a specific problem, I'm just trying to explore in what circumstances I can use builtins for things like count-leading/trailing-zeros, popcount, and so on.

Comment: What GCC version are you using? Does compiling in verbose mode (`-v`) give any extra hints?

Comment: This is with either gcc 6.4.0 or gcc 7.3.0 (macports versions). Running in verbose mode says that it's using `/opt/local/bin/as`, which is `Apple Inc version cctools-895, GNU assembler version 1.38`, right before the errors.

Comment: I learned that this issue [has already been noted](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/37846) with the version of `as` that MaPorts supplies. The work-around is to add `-Wa,-q` to the invocation of gcc. Then it will use `$prefix/clang` as the assembler instead of `$prefix/as`.